# Refactor the python design patterns

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a class called resources and I have defined one method called get_connect. I want to use the data of which get_connect returns to the other classes. I need at least three classes and I use the data of get_connect and I have to parse that data. To implement this I have written the code below

```
class resources:
    @staticmethod
    def get_connect():       
        
        return 1 + 2


class Source1(resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = resources.get_connect()

    def get__details1(self):
        print(self.response)

class Source2(resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = resources.get_connect()
    def get_details2(self):
        print(self.response)

class Source3(resources):
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = resources.get_connect()
    def get__detail3(self):
        print(self.response)

source1 = Source1()
source2 = Source2()
source3 = Source3()
source1.get__details1()
source2.get_details2()
source3.get__detail3()
```

But the problem with the code is for every class in init method I am calling the get_connect method. I don't want to repeat the code. I need help for avoiding redundancy which I have asked below

1. Is there any way I can call get_connect in one place and use it for other classes maybe a decorator or anything? if yes how can I?
2. While creating objects also I am calling each class and calling each method every time. is there a way to use any design pattern here?

If anyone helps me with these oops concepts it will be useful.

Comment: Why do you need three classes that all do the same and then a superclass on top? All you need is one class in total.

Comment: All these three classes will do differently in my actual scenario. That's why I have created three different classes. In this example I have shown same thing

Comment: btw, why do you inherit from `resources` and still use `resources.get_connect`? also are you sure that those classes will do completely different things that can't possibly be done by one class? so far they don't do that, especially considering that all of them get their `response` in the same way

Comment: Yes, It's working without inheriting the resources also. Thanks. Yes, I need three classes as per the requirements. I have to parse the response I get from get_connect. But what I need to know here is there any other better way to call the get_connect and use it in the three classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, is there any reason why you are using `get_connect` method as static?

Because what you can do here is declare it in the parent class:

```
class resources:

    def __init__(self):
        self.response = self.get_connect()

    def get_connect(self):
        return 1 + 2
```

This way you do not need to define the `__init__` method on every class, as it will be automatically inherited from the parent.

Regarding the second question, it really depends on the context, but you can use a strategy pattern in order to retrieve the class that you require to call. For this rename the method of get details into the same for each of the classes, as basically they're used for the same purpose, but changed on the context of the class implementation:

```
class Source1(resources):
    def get_details(self):
        print(self.response)

class Source2(resources):
    def get_details(self):
        print(self.response)

class Source3(resources):
    def get_details(self):
        print(self.response)

classes = {
    "source_1": Source1,
    "source_2": Source2,
    "source_3": Source3
}


source_class = classes["source_1"]
source = source_class()
source.get_details()
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: there is a reason to use `get_connect` as static because now you have an unused argument `self`

Comment: Well, it's an instance method, so it will use `self`, and usually the methods aren't that simplistic as `return 1+2`, methods may use other aspects/logic of the class. But in any case class methods can be used as well.

Comment: More likely, you'll still need to define `__init__` in the child classes and call `super().__init__` in each. Just as much repetition, but it's hard to tell if that's avoidable in this simplified example.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you don't have to override the `__init__` for other implementations, you don't declare it in the child class